# Manually Generate csv file form select statement PL/SQL

Tags: csv, plsql, utl-file

I'm actually having problem generating a CSV file from a select statement that output a lot of rows (close to 10 M). I need to export the result of this statement in a CSV file and since i only have a Citrix VM, i'm being disconnect every 2h, which is not giving me enought time to execute my query.

My though was to start the query and use UTL_FILE to generate a CSV file on our server. But now, i am facing security issues -» I only have read access and cannot create procedure (as ASK TOM articlle https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537857800346182134)

I want to know if you guys knows how could i generate a CSV file on my server by only executing a query and letting it goes?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have directory access to the server from inside the database?

Comment: If your talking about CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY function, the answer is no! :/

Comment: No, do you have write access to such directories created on your behalf? Or are you still setting `UTL_FILE_DIR` parameter in the `init.ora` file?

Comment: I have a read only access to the Database and since i'm running a VM , i'm not sure where to find the init.ora file. i can however create directory and files manually on the server with file explorer.